# Customer log in without being registered to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, login

I am making a website inside of office 365 with sharepoint. I would like to have a small subset of maybe 10 users who have a log in and can login and do some very small things on the website such as upload a file to a database or change some fields in a table.

My question is, is there a way to have users unlicensed with sharepoint and still be able to log in and do some small things? Or must every single user who logs into SharePoint must have a paying account?

Are there any plugins that allow you to manage say, customer log in? Where those user would not be SharePoint users per-say, but more liked signed up users?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You totally can do this, using external users in SharePoint Online, and there are no licensing fees involved, and it is totally supported by Microsoft.

In your tenant administration site, hightlight a site collection and click the "sharing" icon.

[image]

Then select the button reading "allow users who accept sharing invitations and sign in as authenticated users".

[image]

It actually initiates an invitation process, and the user is added to the site once the recipient follows the instructions in the email he receives.  It's a pretty sweet feature, although some of my clients think the Live ID dependency is confusing for their less tech-savvy partners.

More info -

http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2013/08/23/office-365-sharepoint-online-managing-external-users/

Comment: Cool! And then I presume you can give different permissions to different users that log in? So for example, some users can view some pages while others can't?

Comment: Yes.  By default, when you click "Share" to add users, they get put in the members group by default. But if you click "Show options" in the share dialog you can select a group to put them into.  And once they accept the invitation and log in they can be treated as regular SharePoint users just like everyone else. I'd suggest trying it out using a personal MS account and getting familiar with the process.

Comment: What exactly is the issue some of your clients have with the Live ID dependency? That is, what were their complaints?

Comment: Try explaining what a Live ID is to your grandmother.  I know it's difficult for technical people to visualize the difficulties end users have with concepts that come naturally to us, but that's often the case in the wild.